# Data-sync design in .net

Tags: c#, xamarin, asp.net-core, data-synchronization, synchronization

I have an existing cloud based solution with a web api that brokers data to and from the backend SQL database to client applications.  All very standard.  My web api is built using .NET Core.  This is working well and I utilise the existing web api with various web clients that have been built.  The architecture looks like this:

[image: Current solution]
The current solution needs to be extended to support native mobile client applications using the web api (nothing out of the ordinary here - normally they'd call the web api the same as any other client) **BUT** I have to meet the requirement that these new client applications can be used in an offline scenario.  This means I cannot expect a data connection to exist on the device in order to call my web api every time I need.  I need to look at synchronising data so it can be offline and sent back to the server when needed.

Thinking about it, the data will be synchronised in one of two ways:

- One-way sync - data from the server to client but no changes will be
  made to this data e.g. system lookup tables.
- Two-way sync - existing
  data will be synchronised to the client, modified and sent back to
  the server OR new data is created on the client and sent up e.g. new
  order.

New architecture will be as follows:

[image]

So - getting to my question - does anyone know of a good design pattern to follow with regards synchronising data (one-way and two-way) OR maybe a NuGet Package which has synchronisation code built in?  I'm trying to avoid reinventing the wheel with regards sync, if possible.

NOTE: Just for information purposes, the native mobile apps will be built using Xamarin in Visual Studio 2015.

Answer (score 0):

I've not used it yet (just starting to look into as I have a similar situation to yours) but it looks like Xamarin has facility for this already (if you're using Azure anyway...):
[Offline Data Sync in Azure Mobile Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-offline-data-sync)